# Is blender a good solution for making a PCB enclosure

Tags: modeling, 3d-printing

I want to make a custom PCB enclosure . I was looking at the various alternatives out there and was wondering if Blender is a good choice. Also I was planning on getting it 3d printed. However on my model I would probably need to make four holes for the screws on my board to sit into the enclosure. So what should be a good starting point considering I havent used blender extensively before. Should I move over to some other software which suits my needs better? If so could someone please point that out for me?

Comment: I have not done this, but by the sounds of it Blender can be used for this kind of task example: http://www.blendernation.com/2012/03/02/raspberry-pi/

Comment: Most likely the answer is **yes**. but it would help if you would link to some items showing the complexity you would expect.

Answer (score 1):

- Blender has much more than you need to make a case model.
- You have to understand Blender good before you're able to work efficiently though.
- It's same with most programs suitable for this purpose though.

Comment: Are there any sample case models that I can use as a base or are there any tutorials out there for making a case model.

Comment: I really doubt it. General modelling is a too trivial task, thus it has tons of uses. One can't make a tutorial for every use.

Comment: As for modelling - here you go: http://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/68152